# Python - Global variable not passing through to function

Tags: python, global-variables

### DefTest.py

```
def fun1():
    print x
```

### test.py

```
import DefTest

x = 1

DefTest.fun()
```

Why do I get "NameError: global name 'x' is not defined" when executing test.py?  How do I properly set this up so I can grab this function

Comment: why cant you just pass it as argument? why use global variables ?

Comment: `func1` is in a module and you have to set the attribute of the module (`DefTest.x = 1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each module has its own global scope. `fun` uses `DefTest.x`, not `test.x`.

```
>>> import DefTest
>>> DefTest.x = 5
>>> DefTest.fun()
5
```

You might think the following would also work

```
from DefTest import x
x = 5
DefTest.fun()
```

but it doesn't, because `from DefTest import x` creates a new global variable in the module `test` which is *initialized* using the value of `DefTest.x`, rather than creating an "alias" to `DefTest.x`.

Answer (score 0):

in test.py, use the fully qualified name: `deftest.x = 1`

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the variable name x with the Package DefTest in the test.py file

```
DefTest.x = 1
DefTest.func1()
```